# android picking multiple songs using intent

Tags: android, android-intent, media-player

i am trying to integrate media-player in my app.
where it has to pick multiple songs .
then play them in a queue . one after other.
for now i can pick a single song only.

```
problem is how can i pick multiple songs .
```

here is what i am doing for picking single song.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
    android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
  i.setType(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.CONTENT_TYPE);
  startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

any suggestions ..

Comment: i had done this my self :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had made a demo project for this if some one stuck at same issue this demo will help them
**Android Pick Multi Songs** 
    [Android pick multiple Songs](https://github.com/shujat89/androidMultiSongSelectGallery)